# How to make a list of line " wallpapers/original/1.jpg " in incremental order in notepad?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

How to make a list of lines in incremental order in notepad?

For example:

[image]

I mean I want to make 9999 lines in incremental order like the example.

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a python script in Notepad++.

1. Install "Python Script" plugin
2. Create a script *via* “Plugins > Python Script > New Script” and give it a name

   - ````
         editor.appendText("wallpaper/original/"+str(i)+".jpg\n")```
     ````
3. New file
4. Run the script: “Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > Select the file you have just created”
5. Done

Comment: May be you'll find informations [here](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-exception-access-violation-error-on-windows-10/) or ask a new question  https://superuser.com/